# JsonNET decode with list

Tags: json.net, json

I'm using Json.Net to DeserializeObject Json data.

This is my Json

```
string datosContratos = {"Total":1,"Contrato":[{"Numero":1818,"CUPS":"ES003L0P","Direccion":"C. O  ","TextoCiudad":"MADRID","Tarifa":"2"}]}
```

My classes are:

```
public class Contrato
{
    public int Numero;
    public String Cups;
    public String Direccion;
    public String TextoCiudad;
    public String Tarifa;
}

public class Contratos 
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public List<Contrato> ListaContratos { get; set; }
}
```

when I deseralize:

```
Contratos contratos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contratos>(datosContratos);
```

And the result is that contratos.Total is correct (in this case 1) but the `ListaContratos` is null although it should be filled with the data. I don't see the problem!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class must have the same variable names as your JSON, so it should look like this:

```
public class Contratos 
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public List<Contrato> Contrato { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! It works. I was supposing that decoding was based in the type, not in the variable name. Error for me

Answer (score 2):

In your `JSON` string there is attribute called `Contrato`,whereas in your class the list of `Contrato` is declared as `ListaContratos`

change json string to

```
string datosContratos = {"Total":1,
                         "ListaContratos ":[{"Numero":1818,
                                             "CUPS":"ES003L0P",
                                             "Direccion":"C. O  ",
                                             "TextoCiudad":"MADRID",
                                             "Tarifa":"2"}]}
```

**OR**

change class definition to

```
public class Contratos 
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public List<Contrato> Contrato { get; set; }
}
```